# How to assign SQLite databse value to buttons by random

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database with 6 column: id, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4 And 10 row

I want to assign randomly question to a textview and answer_1,2,3,4 to 4button
how can I do that?

```
public String getRandomQustion() {
    Cursor c = mydb.query("content" + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", 
        new String[]{ "question" }, 
        null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
    }     
    else { 
        return "nothing"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, so far?

Comment: @zezollo i have this code to load random question,but dont know how get answers of that row,,,     public String getRandomQustion() {
        Cursor c = mydb.query("content" + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[]{ "question" }, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst())
            return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
        else
            return "nothing";
    }

Comment: The code you posted as comment should be written in your questionn instead (you should edit your question). Otherwise you'll have little chance to get an answer but good chances to get downvotes.